# Use linked file as input to linker

Tags: linker, blcr

Does linux have a way to use a statically linked file as input. Specifically, I'd like to add the BLCR libcr library to a statically linked program for which  I do not have access to the source code.

Comment: This is exactly what people usually do, and this is what the linker is for. To link libraries with other objects. Your question is unclear.

Comment: Yes, I see, let me try again: Is there a linker for linux that I can use to add a library to an already linked program by using the linked program and the new library as input. I do not have access to the source or object codes. E.g.   ld -o newprogram -lcr  a.out    where newprogram has libcr linked in to the a.out program